# tf.gradients - dimensions of output

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, dimensions

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3],name='x')
W_1 = tf.get_variable('W_1', [3,3], dtype = tf.float32, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0))
layer_out = tf.matmul(x, W_1, name = 'layer_out')
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run([tf.gradients(layer_out, [x])], feed_dict = {x: np.array([[1,7,5]])} )
```

it returns:

```
[[array([[3., 3., 3.]], dtype=float32)]]
```

I am expecting to get 3 by 3 matrix or as per `tf.gradients` docs list of dim 3 with 3 elements for each list entry.

What I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

I see in docs [tf.gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients)

```
A list of sum(dy/dx) for each x in xs
```

but why sum and how do I get all entries of Jacobian?